# Starting the Turtlebot on 11.04 as a non turtlebot user

Tags: ros, turtlebot, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After having followed the setup instructions:

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/diamondback/Robot%20Setup
http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Networking%20Setup
```

I'm attempting to start the turtlebot service,as suggested here:

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/TurtleBot%20Bringup
```

But no such service can be found.  There is a file called

```
/usr/sbin/turtlebot-start
```

and when I run this I get:

```
/usr/sbin/turtlebot-start: line 28: setuidgid: command not found
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, and have installed the electric rather than the diamondback version (ros-electric-turtlebot-robot).

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

[Supplemental]

If I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install daemontools setuidgid
```

Then edit /usr/sbin/turtlebot-start and change "turtlebot" in the setuidgid command to a valid user then I am able to run this script.  However, I then get:

```
Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.
```

The create base is switched on and the cable is connected.  I can see that /dev/ttyUSB0 does exist.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11560/starting-the-turtlebot-on-11.04-as-a-non-turtlebot-user/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-10-15**:
That's more successful, although I get the following:  [WARN] [WallTime: 1318702992.358059] Invalid OI Mode 4
[WARN] [WallTime: 1318702992.359357] Invalid Charging Source 184, actual value: 184

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-15**:
Can you please post the error message that you get when executing 'roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that the user you have chosen has permissions to the port.  We setup the udev rules for the user turtlebot in the official ISO.  See this question http://answers.ros.org/question/2145/cant-access-turtlebot-through-ttyusb0

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2